# Make a new font from another one

Tags: linux, fonts

I was casting around for a solution for to another question I had ( [Stretch text in inkscape, but then wrap it to a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711714/stretch-text-in-inkscape-but-then-wrap-it-to-a-path) ) and I wondered if it was possible to easily and programmatically make one font from another? As a concrete example, can I take FreeSerif font, double its height, and produce another font, calling it FreeSkinnySerif? (I could then use FreeSkinnySerif in Inkscape and get the effect I'm after.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FontForge Scripting](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/scripting-alpha.html#Scale) might work for you, in particular [scale](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/scripting-alpha.html#Scale). I suggest trying out the command in the GUI first, than create [the script](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/scripting.html).

Comment: Thanks. I've marked this as the correct answer as it was exactly the kind of tool I was hoping to learn about. In the GUI, load FreeSerif (from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont), ctrl-A to select all, right-click, transform, scale, set X to 50%. Save as. (I'm having trouble installing/viewing/using the font, so maybe it doesn't work correctly, but I'll keep playing with it.)

Comment: ...Don't use "Save As". Use File|Generate Fonts. I also needed to go into Element|Font Info, and change the name, and change em size to be a power of 2. Validate gives other complaints, which I ignored. I moved my new font to ~/.fonts, then ran `sudo fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts/`. Then I could use my new font in Inkscape (for instance).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a scripting solution, but have you tried the SVG Font editor that is built in to Inkscape?

Text->SVG Font Editor.

I guess that you could make a python script that used it somehow, but simply using the tool from inkscape would probably bee faster.

[Here is a tutorial.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KX-e6sijGE)

Comment: Thanks John, that looks promising (at least if you just need a few glyphs - it would be hard work with a full font). I'm using Inkscape 0.47, but it simply won't work for me: I click "Get curves from selection" and nothing happens; no error message just nothing appears. I have the glyph in the preview text. I tried the Path|Union step. (Not your problem, I can see in the video it should be working!)

Comment: Convert the letter to a path, then use the node selection tool to select all the nodes in the path.
Then click get curves from selection

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm doing that. I've done Path|Object To Path. I'm using the "Edit paths by node" tool. At the bottom it says "23 of 23 nodes selected in 2 of 2 subpaths". Over in the Font Editor I click glyph 1, click "Get curves from selection...", but nothing happens; no error message, but no preview. (If I have no glyph selected I get an error for that, if I have no object selected I get an error for that...)

Comment: Aha! It was just the preview that was broken. I saved the svg file, used the online site to convert to a ttf, and I have a font! I installed it, and can use it in Inkscape to wrap it to a path! (Baseline info is completely wrong, so it looks terrible; I wonder if that is why preview did not work?)